Error miniting token for user in next js typescript
I'm trying to mint my tokens for initial users
this is my frontend code I'm calling the mintTokensForUser function but the error I'm getting is
icoPage.tsx:44 Error minting tokens: 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at eval (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:510:53)
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at objectName (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:510:15)
    at describeObjectForErrorMessage (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:608:17)
    at describeObjectForErrorMessage (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:744:22) ```

export const MintTokensForm = () => {
    const { publicKey, signTransaction } = useWallet();
    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const [solAmount, setSolAmount] = useState('');
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');

    const TOKEN_OWNER = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOL_TOKEN_OWNER_KEY_PAIR || ''
    const TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS = new PublicKey(address.address) || ''

    const ownerArray = Uint8Array.from(TOKEN_OWNER.split(',').map(Number))
    const OWNER: Keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(ownerArray)

    // console.log(ownerArray)
    const handleMint = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!publicKey) {
          setStatus('Please connect your wallet first.');
          return;
        }
        setStatus('Minting tokens...');
        try {


          await mintTokensForUser(
            TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS,
            OWNER,
            publicKey,
            connection          );
    
          setStatus('Tokens minted successfully!');
        } catch (error:any) {
          console.error('Error minting tokens:', error);
          setStatus(`Error minting tokens: ${error.message}`);
        }
      };
    

this is the code being called
"use server";

import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Transaction, clusterApiUrl, sendAndConfirmTransaction } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { createMintToInstruction, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount } from '@solana/spl-token'
import {  MINT_PRICE, PAID_MINT_AMOUNT } from './index'


export const mintTokensForUser = async (
    tokenMint: PublicKey, 
    OWNER: Keypair, 
    userPublicKey: PublicKey,
    connection: Connection
  ): Promise<void> => {
    const userTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      OWNER, 
      tokenMint,
      userPublicKey
    )
  
    const transaction = new Transaction()
  
    transaction.add(
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: userPublicKey,
        toPubkey: OWNER.publicKey,
        lamports: MINT_PRICE
      })
    )
  
    const mintToInstruction = createMintToInstruction(
      tokenMint,
      userTokenAccount.address,
      OWNER.publicKey,
      PAID_MINT_AMOUNT
    )
    transaction.add(mintToInstruction)
  
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection, 
      transaction, 
      [OWNER] 
    )
  
    console.log(` ${signature}`)
  }
  


You are loading the Keypair to the frontend. You should not be doing that. Anyone could obtain your keypair and steal your funds. Keypairs should never be exposed to the frontend.
The way to do this in the frontend is to build the instructions and sign it with the connected wallet. So, once you have built the transaction, you need to send it to the frontend for the user to sign it. You cannot sign the transaction in the backend with the user's wallet.
const tx = await mintTokensForUser(
            TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS,
            OWNER, // -> change it to the publickey of the user's wallet
            publicKey,
            connection          );
await signTransaction(tx);

But you will have some issues when sending the tx from the backend to the frontend, because you need to serialize it.
You can try to deserialize it with "superjson":
import {
  PublicKey,
  Transaction,
  Message,
  TransactionInstruction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import superjson from "superjson";

superjson.registerClass(PublicKey, {
  identifier: "PublicKey",
});
superjson.registerCustom<
  Transaction,
  { data: number[]; hasSignatures: boolean }
>(
  {
    deserialize: (obj) => {
      if (obj.hasSignatures) {
        return Transaction.from(obj.data);
      }
      return Transaction.populate(Message.from(obj.data));
    },
    serialize: (tx) => {
      if (tx.signatures.length) {
          return { data: tx.serialize().toJSON().data, hasSignatures: true };
      }
       return {
          hasSignatures: false,
          data: tx.serializeMessage().toJSON().data,
        };
    },
    isApplicable: (val): val is Transaction => val instanceof Transaction,
  },
  "Transaction",
);

Anyway to avoid the serialization/deserialization part, it might just be easier to build the tx in the frontend in your case.
